# Download in JS a ZIP file created in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zip

I want to download a zip file created via a PHP method.
When user clicks on a "download" icon, the zip is created and should be automatically downloaded.

The zip creation works fine. The PHP method ends like this:

```
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"archive.zip\"");
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path_archive));
    readfile($path_archive);
    return;
```

This is the AJAX method in my JS file. *path* is needed for my function to create the archive.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_of_PHP_method",
        data : { path : path },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) { 
            var uriContent = "data:application/zip;" + data;
            var myWindow = window.open(uriContent, "archive.zip");
            myWindow.focus();
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, the downloaded file is called "download".
It has no extension and even if I rename it with a .zip extension, there's an error opening it:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.
```

Hae you guys encountered the same issue ? I've found similar questions on this site but none faced the same situation. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax cannot be used to download a file because of security issues. You can create a regular hyperlink to your php script that does the action and the browser will show up the save download dialog without leaving the current page you are in.

**Sample code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
location.href = "url_of_PHP_method";
</script>
```

Comment: @Raidenade yep, sorry, I figured I could not write code in a comment. Thanks for your answer. I am currently catching the user's click via $("body").on("click",".download", function() { ... } )                     and this calls a JS method containing only the AJAX I posted above.

Comment: So I wonder how I could replace this, as you're telling me to create another hyperlink

Comment: What you have to do is, in the click method, make a regular `$.get` call (not ajax) to the php script. Thats all you have to do. The php script will create the zip file then echo it using `readfile()` as it is doing now.

Comment: Thanks again @Raidenace, but with a regular `$.get`, nothing happens.

Comment: @Charlie I guess I confused by mentioning `$.get` When I said use a regular hyperlink I meant `location.href`. Let me update answer with a sample code.